# What is the longest six in cricket history?

Tags: cricket, history, trivia, statistics, records

Calculating the distance of the six hit by the batsmen is a new trend.

I'd searched for longest six of cricket, some said it's from [Shahid Afridi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPCgWL4a4lM), some said, it's [MSD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwM6u3Wo9fo) and some saying [Yuvi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrjbLsSM4JU).

I would like to know

> What is the longest six in International cricket matches?

ie, Domestic matches like IPL is not a matter here.

As this question is based on stats and could be modified in future, an answer with link will be better.

Comment: I hope someone has made an effort to recalculate historical/modern sixes on the bases of stadium sizes, rooftop heights, etc. But here are [a few candidates](http://upcric.com/live-cricket-score/cricket-videos/longest-six-in-cricket-history.html) to enjoy in the meantime. :)

Comment: Performance doesn't seem to be an appropriate tag IMO. Since a player can hit a log six by good timing too. :)

Comment: These are two questions. I think you should ditch the shortest six part of the question. Perhaps ask it in a different question. [This here](http://youtu.be/y2sjjQ4cpyA) seems a very funny candidate, but the [scorecard](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/66180.html) shows this to be 5 penalty runs: hence no six for the batsman.

Comment: @aufkag, Question edited.

Comment: I don't know more about it but was there any technology/method to measure the distance of six few years ago?

Comment: There is [an article in cricinfo](http://www.thecricketmonthly.com/story/1026113/the-longest-shot) about longest Sixes.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>YouTube is notoriously unreliable when it comes to records claims, so I am answering this question with a *candidate* for the longest six in international cricket that at least has a somewhat more reliable reference. I am not claiming this is the record holder.</sup>

---

### Mark Waugh from Daniel Vettori, 1997

[Test no. 1386](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/63770.html) | 1997/98 season
Played at Western Australia Cricket Association Ground, Perth
20,21,22,23 November 1997 (5-day match)

> Under the Perth floodlights, which were switched on after tea, the first such use in Tests, he on-drove Vettori more than 130 yards [119 meters] on to the roof of the five-tier Lillee-Marsh Stand, a shot many locals believed to be the biggest six at the WACA ground.

<sup>[*Wisden*](http://www.espncricinfo.com/wisdenalmanack/content/story/153358.html)</sup>

> He proceeded to score 86, including a lofted drive from Daniel Vettori onto the roof of the Lillee-Marsh Stand. The ball travelled approximately 130 m, one of the longest sixes in history.

<sup>[*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Waugh#1996_World_Cup)</sup>

Here is [YouTube](http://youtu.be/Mut3hDds-gY) footage of the shot.

[image]

Comment: Afridi's hit vs Symonds at this very venue, 2004/05 (Game 8, VB Series) drew following instantaneous reactions from Bil Lawry was: "_O ho ho!! That is the biggest six! That is the biggest six you ever seen. Afridi has launched it on the top of the stand_". Later on Sky Sports, Ian Ward discussed it and guests claimed Afridi six is well ahead of Mark Waugh's six you mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

Shahid Afridi hit the biggest six in cricket history against South Africa in 2013 in his 88 runs innings. The distance of the six measured 158 meters.

1. SHAHID AFRIDI - 160 m
2. SHAHID AFRIDI - 158 m
3. MARTIN GUPTILL - 129 m
4. KIERON POLLARD - 125 m
5. ALBIE MORKEL - 124 m
6. THISARA PERERA-123m
7. CHRIS GAYLE - 120 m
8. CHRIS GAYLE - 119 m
9. M.S. DHONI - 112.6 m
10. CHRIS GAYLE - 112 m

Comment: Where does this list come from?

Comment: You need a source

Comment: Lol. 160 m !!!!!!!!! 100% wrong